# Grub2: stdin: invalid argument

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, grub2, ubuntu-20.04

I have attempted to create a UEFI pen drive that installs Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop 64-bit.
The `exFAT` partition `gpt2` contains the entire Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system image.
The `FAT32` partition `gpt1` contains the following files:

```
.
├── boot
│   └── grub
│       └── x86_64-efi
│           └── exfat.mod
└── EFI
    └── BOOT
        ├── BOOTX64.EFI
        ├── grub.cfg
        ├── grubx64.efi
        └── mmx64.efi

5 directories, 5 files
```

where the `grub.cfg` file contains the following lines:

```
insmod exfat
set root='hd0,gpt2'
search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid 0DAD-2CC8
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

After changing the `Secure Boot` method from `Deployed Mode` to `Audit Mode`, the default `grub.cfg` file of the `exfat` partition is called correctly from the `grub.cfg` file of the `FAT32` partition.
In fact, the correct installation options appear.
After selecting the `Ubuntu` option, loops endlessly and pressing the `ESC` key I realize that the cause is an unspecified error: `stdin: invalid argument`, which is repeated many times.
What could be the cause of this error?

UPDATE 1: Even disabling secure boot completely, the same error appears.

Comment: There exist several programs that can create the boot media for you. Why do you try to do it yourself?

Comment: Why don't they do it in exfat and I want to provide my own script to do it with a single terminal function, which I have already completed.

Comment: Are you aware of what is missing or wrong to make the boot work?

Comment: For one, I think Ubuntu does not like exFAT.  Try FAT32.

Comment: I still want to make exfat work.